# Default Filter in GridView with Yii2

Tags: php, sorting, gridview, filter, yii2

I don't know how to set the filter default of GridView. It's mean when page loaded, it's will load the filter with specific condition that I've set.

Any idea for this?
Thanks

Comment: Provide Your Specific conditons in `SearchModel` class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by using the search model .

I am using Default Gii generated code to explain the ways

```
public function actionIndex()
{
     $searchModel = new UserSearch(); 
     $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

     return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
}
```

Say you want a dynamic filter when the page is loaded

use the link as

> ../index.php?r=user/index&UserSearch[id]=7

This will add a filter where id = 7 ie in my case since id is the primary key only one user will be listed

Say if you want always apply a filter without showing anything in the url

```
public function actionIndex()
{
     $searchModel = new UserSearch(); 
     $searchModel->name = 'mid'; 
     $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

     return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
}
```

This will create a filter where user's name has string 'mid'

if you want more advanced filters

you can edit the **search()** function in the UserSearch Class there the query used to populate the data and ActiveDataProvider will be available to you .
say you do't want to list users who are inactive .

```
    public function search($params)
    {
         $query = User::find();

         $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
             'query' => $query,
          ]);

         $this->load($params);
         $query->andFilterWhere(['active_status' => 1]);
         ....
```

this method will provide you with limitless ways to filter your results ..
Hope this helps ..

Comment: I have thousands of documents in my collection. Initially I want to load only the docs which have **current date** in `createdAt`. But the index page should be later loadable with all the docs. Is it possible to do this with your answer? please.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and it worked for me

```
public function actionIndex()
{
     $searchModel = new UserSearch(); 
     $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
     $dataProvider->query->andFilterWhere(['status'=>1]); 
     return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
}
```

This helps performing the filter for action is needed and for all,  in my case I needed it alone in an environment

Comment: How to use this if I have `ArrayDataProvider` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function actionIndex()
{

     $searchModel = new UserSearch(); 

     // Filtro por Defecto y Reflejado en Formulario de Filtrado en Grid 
     $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;  
     if (!isset($params['UserSearch'])) {
        $params['UserSearch']['status']=1;            
     }   
     $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($params);   

     // -----------------------------------------------------------     

     return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     ]);
}
```

NOTA: Usar (**!isset($params['UserSearch'])**) para que solo se aplique como **búsqueda por defecto** ('Si no se ha definido ninguna condición de filtrado')

NOTE: Use (**! Isset ($ params ['UserSearch']) **) so that it only applies as a **default search** ('If no filter condition has been defined')

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 [ActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html) it self need a [query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#find()-detail), means you can filter your results when passing it the query object eg:

```
$query = Post::find()->where['status' => 'published'];
// Todo and more conditions with $query object
$provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

much more easier!

```
class YourModelSearch extends \app\models\YourModel
{
    public $status_id = 'published';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but only to keep a record on SO.

One way of setting the allowed filters in a Yii2 `GridView` widget is to use its `filterModel` object's `rules` function to return the wanted filtering fields set with the `save` attributes. So you can remove from this list all the unwanted filters not needed to be displayed in the `GridView`.

You can then customize the `ActiveDataProvider` query under the `search` function of the `filterModel` to properly build the requested filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

If your default gridview filter value comes from an expression, call its property just before `$this->load($params)` in the Search's model method:

```php
class ContractSearch extends Contract
{
    ...

    public $year;
  
    public function search($params)
    {
        $this->year = date('Y');
        $this->load($params);
    }

    ...
}
```