# Yii2 Remove initial Search

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I have been searching for hours on the internet on trying to remove the initial filter on yii2 gridview. All the options point on setting a default value in the search. I would like when the index page loads, that no data is shown in the gridview only when user search. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

```
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5668
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608796/default-filter-in-gridview-with-yii2


<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\models\AnimalSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Animal and Animal Products Search';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //////prevent the dropdown from being populated when the user click back
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
    $("#commodity").val('');
    $("#species").val('');
    $("#finality").val('');
    $("#origin").val('');
});
</script>  


<div class="animal-index">

    <h1 align="center"><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <br>

    <?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>


    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        // 'filterModel' => $searchModel,
       //  'showHeader'=> false,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

           // 'id',

            'commodity',
            'species',
            'finality',
            'origin',
            // 'intendeduse',

            // 'risk',
            // 'conditions',
            // 'scu',
            // 'maf',
            // 'cities',
            // 'fisheries',
            // 'forestry',
            // 'comments',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'visibleButtons' => [
             'update' =>false, // or whatever condition
              'delete' => false,
          ],
        ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: please add grid config and search model to your question

Comment: Updated the question. Just need to remove the initial gridview search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition that would yield no results whenever no search params are present

update your search model to something like this

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Model::find();
    
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    
    // this ensures no rows are returned if nothing was submitted
    if (is_null($params) || empty($params)) {
        $query->where('0 = 1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }
    
    // ....
}
```

Comment: posting your search model would have been more useful. hope this example still helps

Comment: This code works well. I am able to search and it shows empty values on load. Thanks csminb